# Java 11: is there any way we can enforce the maven build not to add or modify the model class

Tags: java, spring, maven-plugin

I have a Model class, with some properties, I don't want this class to be modified by some one either refactor the property or add new property , then build should fail ..

is there any way we can achieve this ? I am using maven, spring boot and java 11 in my project

Comment: please provide more context, a sample project for your issue if possible

Comment: I have a Model class, with some properties, I don't want this class to be modified by some one either refactor the property or add new property , then build should fail ..

Comment: And how would you stop the person doing the refactoring to remove the checks as well?

Comment: What is the reason why "the build should fail"? Why does the model have to be unmodified? What is the scenario in which you use the project? The heading suggests that the maven build process could modify the model, but the text points more to a person - why could the build process manipulate your code, or is the manual modification the thing you want to prevent?

Comment: How are you gonig to stop anyone from forking your Github and making local changes. You cannot!  How you protect your code base is by only letting good quality PRs being accepted.

Comment: Special word "final" ;-)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note is that the person refactoring the class could also remove/change/refactor the code checking that the property exists.

In this answer, I'll create JUnit tests checking for a property. You can then use the Maven surefire plugin or similar to ensure it runs successfully.

It assumes the following class:

```java
class SomeClass{
    private String someProperty;
    public String getSomeProperty(){
        return someProperty;
    }
    public void setProperty(String someProperty){
        this.someProperty = someProperty;
    }
}
```

## Just access it

Your test could just access the property and check whether that works.

```java
@Test
public void checkSomeProperty(){
    SomeClass o = new SomeClass();
    assertEquals(YOUR_EXPECTED_DEFAULT_VALUE, o.getSomeProperty());
    o.setSomeProperty("something else");
    assertEquals("something else", o.getSomeProperty());
}
```

However, note that refactoring tools would probably also refactor that test (e.g. change the name of the property in tests).

## Reflection

If you don't want refactoring tools to easily pick up your checks, you can use reflection to check for its existence.

```java
@Test
public void checkSomePropertyWithReflection() throws NoSuchFieldException, NoSuchMethodException {
    Field field = SomeClass.class.getDeclaredField("someProperty");
    assertEquals(String.class, field.getType());
    Method getter = SomeClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("getSomeProperty");
    assertEquals(String.class, getter.getReturnType());
    Method setter = SomeClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("setSomeProperty", String.class);
    assertEquals(void.class, setter.getReturnType());
    //maybe further checks
}
```

note that this test just checks whether the field and accessors exist.

## Should you do this?

After all, refactoring is a good thing. Normally, you shouldn't try to prevent it. Instead of creating tests to prevent certain methods of refactoring, create tests that actually check whether everything works. This makes it easy to refactor your code in ways that make it better without breaking anything.